# if the hardware wallet company ledger goes out of business, what will happen to my crypto asset / private keys in ledger?

Tags: wallets

if the hardware wallet company ledger goes out of business, what will happen to my crypto asset / private keys in ledger? I heard that the hardware wallet ledger is not open-source, so will the company get access to my private key? Will I be able to transfer my crypto elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware should continue to work, firmware no longer will be updated, their software ledger live will stop working.

Wallets that do not depend on ledger services like MEW or MyCrypto will continue to work.

It doesn't seem the hardware has the ability to be accessed remotely so if you don't connect it to the internet it should be safe.

If you have backup the mnemonic you don't need their hardware at all.

Comment: To add to this: only use your recovery mnemonic phrase if you cannot access your hardware wallet in any other way.

Comment: @Morten , what do you mean by "cannot access your hardware wallet"?

Comment: mnemonic meaning the seed phrase?

Comment: @user35843905830509118 Yes, seed phrase or mnemonic.

Comment: "Cannot access your hardware wallet" as in, you lost your device, the device is broken, etc.

Comment: @Morten might I ask the reasons for your first comment ?

Comment: @user35843905830509118 It should be possible to use the mnemonic at any time, but doing so while the hardware still works kinda defeat its purpose. Usage without proper care might compromise it.